# Sage: How do I pass PHP data from extras.php into scripts.js using wp_localize_script()?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to do a test AJAX request, in my theme - built with Sage. So I need to make my scripts.js file aware of the correct URL to WP's AJAX processing script.

This is in scripts.js:

```
console.log(resources_ajax.ajax_url);
```

and this is in extras.php

```
wp_localize_script( 'sage/js', 'resources_ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ));
```

I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: resources_ajax is not defined

Which would lead me to believe I have the wrong handle as the first parameter of wp_localize_script...but I looked at where scripts.js is enqued (which also registers it) and it's this:

```
 wp_enqueue_script('sage/js', Assets\asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);
```

So I'm not sure why the data isn't getting passed in.

Comment: Are you enqueuing the file i.e calling wp_enqueue_script after the wp_localize_script function is called or before it? The order is important.

Comment: I was not! I was trying to localize the script before the script was enqueued. Thank you for the help ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the script is registered before the wp_localize_script function is called.
So it should be in the order:

```
wp_enqueue_script('sage/js', Assets\asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true); 
wp_localize_script( 'sage/js', 'resources_ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ));
```

More reference here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Thank you! (and typing this for the benefit of those using Sage and struggling with localization) you if want to localize a script in Sage - like main.js - you'll want to do the above in `setup.php` which is where Sage enques scripts.